# Error: "Security/No-assign-param": Avoid assigning to function parameters

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I use this function to convert type uint256 to string.But i get error message about "Security/No-assign-param"

```
function converIntToString(uint number) internal view returns(string){

    if (number == 0) 
        return "0";
    uint j = number;
    uint length;
    while (j != 0){
        length++;
        j /= 10;
    }

    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
    uint k = length - 1;
    while (number != 0){
        bstr[k--] = byte(48 + number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }

    return string(bstr);

}
```

I am using VSCode and I did not encounter the same problem on Remix IDE

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning appear when you use the parameter and calculate inside while loop, for suppress one workaround this warning you can use one temporary variable like below:

```
function convertIntToString(uint256 _number) 
internal 
pure 
returns (string) {
    uint256 _tmpN = _number;

    if (_tmpN == 0) {
        return "0";
    } 

    uint256 j = _tmpN;
    uint256 length = 0;

    while (j != 0){
        length++;
        j /= 10;
    }

    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);

    uint256 k = length - 1;

    while (_tmpN != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(48 + _tmpN % 10);
        _tmpN /= 10;
    }

    return string(bstr);

}
```

your function can have `pure` and not `view` because its based on parameters and not read state from smart contract.

Answer (score 3):

## Why you're seeing this error

If you use vscode with `vscode-solidity` extension, it comes with `solium` as linter and `security` ruleset is enabled by default.

If you are to read the [solium-plugin-security README](https://github.com/duaraghav8/solium-plugin-security#readme), you will notice `no-assign-params` means `Disallow assigning to function parameters`.

But nontheless the contract should still compile if you run solc.

## Getting rid of the error

You can either fix this by

- Disable the linter in `vscode-solidity` altogether: Set `"solidity.linter": false` in your vscode user preferences.
- Disable the `security/no-assign-params` rule in either the file, or the line. Please refer to [solium documentation](https://github.com/duaraghav8/Solium#configure-with-comments)
- Fix the security problem pointed out by solium. Make a copy of the param `(uint number)`, so you don't assign value to it in `number /= 10`